# Having trouble using move_uploaded_file() function?

Tags: php

Warning: move_uploaded_file(/videos/): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp1\htdocs\php_avanzado\Modulo7\processVideos.php on line 10

I keep getting that error ^ Sorry for the ambiguity, this is my first time using stackoverflow or a forum pertaining to programming.

```
include('videos.php');

$title = $_REQUEST['title'];
$source = $_FILES['upload']["tmp_name"];
$type = $_REQUEST['type'];
$description = $_REQUEST['desc'];
$duration = '';

if (move_uploaded_file($source, '/videos/')) {
    echo "El archivo es válido y fue cargado exitosamente.\n";
} else {
    echo "¡Posible ataque de carga de archivos!\n";
}
```

Comment: Try and use `'videos/'` if running script from the root of your server. Also make sure the folder is writeable and that your form contains `method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I am trying to move the temp video source to my videos folder but I am getting this error. First I got the permission issue, now I get this.

Comment: I noticed you are using `$_REQUEST`. If your form is `method="get"` it won't work. It must be POST.

Comment: See the answers below.

Comment: my form's method is set to be POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $move . $_FILES["file"]['name'])) {
    echo "Uploaded";
} else {
   echo "File was not uploaded";
}
```

check it out ..

Comment: What does the variable $move contain?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks man. I'll give this a try. I am trying to make a video magazine/sharing site and this is pretty essential.

Comment: @ferrakken, sorry for the tardiness of my response. It certainly got the job done. What I was missing was $_FILES["file"]['name'] which was apparently required for the movement of the file.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file):

> ```
> bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
> ```
>
> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by `filename` is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   **filename** given by `destination`.